# How can I convert string date to date using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have following date time formatted string.

```
04-AUG-2022
```

I need to convert it into following date format. `04 August 2022`. how can I do that, I tried following code.

```
string date = "04-AUG-2022";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MMMM-yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it shows,

> System.FormatException: 'String '04-AUG-2022' was not recognized as a
> valid DateTime`

Comment: The [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for abbreviated month names is MMM, not MMMM. `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` should work

Comment: add below code  hopefully is can solve your problem
            string date = "04-AUG-2022";
            DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

Answer (score 3):

For 'AUG' you need `MMM` not `MMMM`.

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("04-AUG-2022", "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var d2 = DateTime.ParseExact("04-AUGUST-2022", "dd-MMMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like this,

```
string date = "04-AUG-2022";
var formatedDate = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

please just do like this,

```
string date = "04-AUG-2022";
var Updateddate = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: you need to use not tostring cause question is making datetime not string. 
====
//Code
            string date = "04-AUG-2022";
            DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
//end code